# ffmpeg not found

Tags: ffmpeg

As I had to install my system from scratch I decided to play it safe this time around and follow the documentation for compiling ffmpeg on Centos via the ffmpeg.org site. I followed every command line by line without any errors until the very final one which was to do with the bash_profile.

If I look for ffmpeg on my system it just keeps saying command not found?

I don't understand why the documentation installs everything in `~/` when I thought it needs to be in `/usr/bin`.

I don't understand why the documentation doesn't include ldconfig command or any kind of instructions on setting the path and executing the software.

update: I decided to undo what I had done because couldn't work out file paths and instead I downloaded and installed ffmpeg with rpmforge and yum and finally it is all working. I literally began learning terminal last year and it has been a very steep learning curve for me so what may seem very obvious to some eg file paths for setting up ffmpeg is not for me. Hence my great confusion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [. ~/.bash\_profile: No such file or directory](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116991/bash-profile-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: well it is not because on there was told bash profile thing was an error i could ignore

Comment: I AM COMPLETELY STUCK so please don't put this question on hold when the other one is on hold.

Comment: It is the same root issue, though. You haven't followed the instructions on the page properly...

Comment: Explain how I haven't - I have completely line by line.

Comment: "Note: If you do not require certain encoders you may skip the relevant section and then remove the appropriate ./configure option in FFmpeg. For example, if libvorbis is not needed, then skip that section and then remove --enable-libvorbis from the Install FFmpeg section."

Comment: I never said I did not require any encoders. I just added those listed suggested for my system on that page, nothing extra.

Comment: You aren't reading it properly: you have to follow the steps in *every* code box (unless you explicitly don't want that codec)...

Comment: I did follow EVERY code box explicitly and implicitly.

Comment: @jasonwryan Please stop bullying cea. This looks like a legitimate question to me, and your concerns don't seem relevant to the question. Codecs don't relate to `$PATH`.

Comment: @Wutaz I'm not bullying anyone, and you baseless accusation is as misguided as it is unwelcome.

Comment: Either way, there's no need to be so condescending and hostile.

Comment: There is no question mark in your whole text. It reads as if you are just interested in knowing why the documentation for ffmeg is the way it is, i.e. lacking `ldconfig` and not setting the path. Are you interested in getting ffmeg up and running at all? If so, why don't you ask if someone knows how to compile `ffmpeg` on your platform and include the commands that you issued up to where you got stuck?

Comment: All sorted now, I can see how you might think I am just 'pussy footing' about but believe me that is not my intention so I am sorry if you feel I led anyone astray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your previous question, it seems that you followed the instructions too literally. I don't know which part exactly you should focus on (since I installed my ffmpeg manually instead of `make install`), but one of the arguments to `./configure` needs to reflect the proper destination of the program (in your case, I think that means change `$HOME/...` to `/usr/bin/...` This will then be used by `make install` to move the file.

If you don't want to repeat the configuration and install processes, you might be able to modify the `install` target of the makefile directly (if you still have it).

Comment: I need to set the environment variables, ok I get it I think.There is an explanation here : https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/GenericCompilationGuide